# Maintaining ratios of an image within a class, inside a DIV container

Tags: html, css, image, class

The one thing I have difficulty with is maintaining an image ratio. I eventually end up making it work but what I have done in the past are not consistent and it's usually fixed through trial and error.

My question is where do I put the size attributes? On the div container class or image class?
What size attributes should I be including to maintain ratios.

Example:

I have an image inside of a class:

```
#img1 {
background-image: url('image1.jpg');
}
```

I then have a DIV container with another div inside containing the image class:

```
<div class="img-container">

        <div id="img1></div>
    </div>
```

I tried adding:

max-height:100%;
max-width:100%;

to the image class.

and the actual image pixel sizes to the container but that did not work.

Any help and tips/tricks anyone could provide wouldl be awesome! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An img tag will maintain it's ratio naturally, so if possible you're better off using that:

```html
<img src="image1.jpg">
```

If you want to keep your image at the right ratio, while inside a container that has a width or height set, you can try using [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit).

Lastly, if you want to use background-image but also have the image maintain it's ratio, you can use [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).

Try:

```css
#img1 {
  background-image: url('image1.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Note that the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have always assumed that stylings should stay in css away from the html but you are absolutely right it is much easier to add the image in the html as a src

Answer (score 0):

If you know the height and width of the image, you can something like this, where 52.42% is the aspect ratio.

```
//markup
<div class="img1" style="background-img:url('image1.jpg')"></div>

//css
.img1 {
   width: 100%;
   height: 0;
   display: block;
   padding: 52.42% 0 0 0;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
}
```

If you don't care about the original image's aspect ratio and would rather impose your own, the above works as well. The above class will visually crop the image so that it fits the box. The 52.42% aspect ratio is approximately facebooks's post cover image aspect ratio for example.

Answer (score 0):

there is a typo in your code , you missed  end quote while giving id it is not properly closed. so tour #img1 is not getting applied. fix that it should work or follow the working demo link.

```
<div id="img1></div>
```

[working demo](https://codepen.io/mukeshm280/pen/LwRPxL)